# PHP INSERT error when imploding an array with count greater than 2

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, insert, implode

I have this weird problem when trying to INSERT a row into my mysql database.

This is the idea. A range of exercise is listed and you can add a quantity and check the days you want to add this exercise to (Sun, Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat) and that adds it to your diary.

This is my code.

```
$addDiary = array();
$addTimestamp = array();
$addDiary[] = '('.$current_user->id.', '.$_POST['exid_'.$i].', '.$_POST['qty_'.$i].', '.$calories_mod.', '.implode('.', $addTimestamp).')';             
$queryAddDiary = mysql_query("INSERT INTO LHNZ_FT_DIARY (USER_ID, EXERCISE_ID, TIME, CALORIES, TIMESTAMPS) VALUES ".implode(',', $addDiary));
```

I have echoed out the addDiary array and the addTimestamp array and it looks fine to me.

$addTimestamp: 1311206400.1311292800.1311379200

$addDiary: (2, 1, 1, 678, 1311206400.1311292800.1311379200)

That query works beautifully if my $addTimestamp array has a length of 1 or 2. However when the length is greater than 2, it chucks this error.

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '.1311379200)' at line 1

Now. This error is shown if I use '.' or ':' as my implode for $addTimestamp. If I use a letter, or '_' it chucks this error.

> Unknown column '1311206400_1311292800_1311379200' in 'field list'

Any ideas how I can use $addTimestamp with a length greater than 2 (meaning I may do that exercise three days a week... this is where it errors).

Thanks,

- leighton

Comment: It's a bad idea to use POST data directly in your query - as Kami says, you are open to SQL injection. Please, don't use http://bit.ly/phpmsql mysql_* functions in new code. They are no longer maintained and are https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation officially deprecated. Learn about http://php.net/pdo PDO or http://php.net/mysqli MySQLi instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String values in MySQL queries must be enclosed in single quotes.

Instead of:

```
$addDiary[] = '('.$current_user->id.', '.$_POST['exid_'.$i].', '.$_POST['qty_'.$i].', '.$calories_mod.', '.implode('.', $addTimestamp).')';
```

Do:

```
$addDiary[] = '('.$current_user->id.', '.$_POST['exid_'.$i].', '.$_POST['qty_'.$i].', '.$calories_mod.", '".implode('.', $addTimestamp)."')";
```

Although I strongly suggest that you also pass every value through [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)() before gluing it to sql query.